# Best practice for making a multi step form to post adds

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, user-interface

I am working on a post your free adds page.

Its a mobile website I am using **JQM** for the UI design.

My question is what would be the best practice for making this UI design one link which I got after researching in google [**LINK**](http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/wizard/)

explains most of it but it would be really great to have more inputs from any of you who has experience in UI design .

I am including an image which I have designed for the UI to give you a better explanation of my question

Thanks in advance .

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply create several sections and navigate between them. I have created this for you, using JQuery, CSS and jQM's built-in transitions.

The idea is simply hide/show sections by swiping left and right. You can add validation before showing next section if you want. <sup>(1)</sup>

First of all, you need to create a "progress bar" on top of sections. I have used CSS3 `flex` since it is responsive and doesn't require too much code. It is straight-forward.

1. **Progress bar**

   - HTML

     ```
     <div class="ui-content" role="main">
       <div class="progress">
          <p>1</p>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <p>2</p>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <p>3</p>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <p>4</p>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <p>5</p>
        </div>
        <!-- sections here -->
     </div>
     ```
   - CSS

     ```
     .ui-content .progress {
         display: flex;
         display: -webkit-flex;
         flex-flow: row nowrap;
         -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
         justify-content: space-around;
         -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
         width: 100%;
         background: skyblue;
         align-items: center;
         padding: .5em;
     }

     .ui-content .progress * {
         margin: 0;
     }

     .ui-content .progress p {
         background: lightblue;
         height: 22px;
         width: 22px;
         border-radius: 22px;
         text-align: center;
     }

     .ui-content .progress .line {
         border-top: 1px solid black;
         flex-grow: 1;
         -webkit-align-self: center; /* center line on mobile browsers */
         -ms-flex-item-align: center;
         align-self: center;
     }
     ```
2. **Sections and their wrapper**

   - HTML

     ```
     <div class="steps"> <!-- wrapper -->
       <div class="step">
         <!-- contents 1 -->
       </div>
       <div class="step">
         <!-- contents 2 -->
       </div>
       ...etc
     </div>
     ```
   - CSS

     ```
     .ui-content .steps {
        padding: 1em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
     ```
3. **General CSS**

   ```
   .ui-page .ui-content {
      padding:0;
   }

   .ui-content * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   /* active step - progress bar */
   .progress .currentStep {
       background: tomato !important;
       font-weight: bold;
   }
   ```
4. **jQuery**

   ```
   $(document).on("pagecreate", "#wizard", function () {
       $(".step").not(":eq(0)").addClass("ui-screen-hidden");
       $(".step:eq(0)").addClass("active");
       $(".progress p:eq(0)").addClass("currentStep");
       $(".ui-content").on("swipeleft swiperight", function (e) {
           var swipe = e.type,
               nextStep = $(".steps").find(".active").next(".step"),
               prevStep = $(".steps").find(".active").prev(".step");
           switch (true) {
               case (swipe == "swipeleft" && nextStep.length > 0):
                   $(".step.active")
                       .toggleClass("slide out");
                   break;
               case (swipe == "swiperight" && prevStep.length > 0):
                   $(".step.active")
                       .toggleClass("slide out reverse");
                   break;
           }
       });
   }).on("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", ".step", function (e) {
       var elm = $(e.target);
       switch (true) {
           case (elm.hasClass("out") && !elm.hasClass("reverse")):
               $(elm).toggleClass("slide out ui-screen-hidden active");
               $(elm).next(".step").toggleClass("slide in active ui-screen-hidden");
               break;
           case (elm.hasClass("out") && elm.hasClass("reverse")):
               $(elm).toggleClass("slide out ui-screen-hidden reverse active");
               $(elm).prev(".step").toggleClass("slide in active reverse ui-screen-hidden");
               break;
           case (elm.hasClass("in") && !elm.hasClass("reverse")):
               elm.toggleClass("slide in");
               break;
           case (elm.hasClass("in") && elm.hasClass("reverse")):
               elm.toggleClass("slide in reverse");
               break;
       }
       var dot = $(".active").index();
       /* highlight all previous numbers */
       $("p:eq(" + dot + ")").prevAll("p").addBack().addClass("currentStep");
       $("p:eq(" + dot + ")").nextAll("p").removeClass("currentStep");
   });
   ```
5. **Explanation**

   On `pagecreate`, all sections will be hidden except for first one by adding `ui-screen-hidden` which is a built-in class in jQM `display: none;`. Also, `.currentStep` class will be added to first *element* "`p`" in *progress bar*.

   On `swipeleft` or `swiperight`, the code checks if *active* section has any *sibling* section before or after it. If `true`, it moves to that section, otherwise `false`.

   Navigating between sections uses jQM built-in transition, the same ones used for *page* transition. In this demo `.slide` is used, however, you can use any of jQM transitions. `.in`, `.out` and `.reverse` are also built-in transition classes, `.out` is added to *active* section, `.in` is added to next/prev section and `.reverse` combines both aforementioned classes in case you navigate to previous section.

   Listening *Animation End* event(s) `animationend` is used to remove `.in`, `.out` and `.reverse`, in addition to giving *active* section a `.active` class.

   Last block of code is used to update *progress bar* with the number of active section. <sup>*Updated*</sup>

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZzCA2/show)** <sup>(2)</sup> - **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZzCA2/)**

<sup>(1) *This example can be used also as a simple gallery carousel without the need to use plugins.*</sup>

<sup>(2) Tested on iPhone 5 - Safari & Chrome</sup>

Comment: Respect, nice implementation :)

Comment: @VikramAnandBhushan I've edit progress bar's lines CSS code to center lines in mobile browsers. Tested on Safari and Chrome mobile.

Comment: @Omar thanks but I am using the progress bar which I had designed because my boss like it more :(

Comment: @VikramAnandBhushan no worries, it's your call :)

Comment: @Omar Although your slider thing is too good :) . I had to do some changes like instead of swipe I had to add click event for a button to scroll to next page .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55120/discussion-between-omar-and-vikram-anand-bhushan).