# Simple jQuery Swipe to display another div in the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

When the page first opens, it will display the div center content.  I hope that the user sees "Left Content" when the user swipes from left to right, and then the user sees "Right content" when the user swipes from right to left on his or her touch enabled device.

```
<div id=center> Center Content </div>
<div id=left> Left Content </div>
<div id=right> Right Content </div>
```

JS code

```
<Script>
   $littlekid = $(document);

   $littlekid.ready(

   function () {
       $littlekid.on("swiperight", function () {
           // alert("swiperight");

           $littlekid.pagecontainer("change", "index.html#left",

           {
               transition: "slide",
               reverse: true
           });

       } // End of function( )
       ) // End of $littlekid.on( ) the first one
       .on("swipeleft", function () {
           // alert("swipeleft");

           $littlekid.pagecontainer("change", "index.html#right",

           {
               transition: "slide",
               reverse: true
           });

       } // End of function

       ); // End of $littlekid.on() second

   });
</script>
```

If I uncomment `alert("swipeleft");` and `alert("swiperight");` I can see the alert just fine.

Comment: `change` is used to change pages not content within same page.

Comment: Then what should I use?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24043188/1771795