# Slide in individual div from right/left with jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to achive an "section slide with previous and next". The sections are marked up like this:

```
<section class="active">
Section 1
</section>

<section>
Section 2
</section>

<section>
Section 3
</section>

<ul class="pager">
    <li><a href="#" class="prev" data-navsec="prev">Prev</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="next" data-navsec="next">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

All sections are hidden except the one with the `active` class.

And I want next and previous sections to slide in from left when previous, and right when next.

The slide functionality doesn't exist with jQuery Mobile what I could see. But I found it does with jQuery UI. So I included that library.

However, there is still a problem. I'm only able to specify the direction where the element will slide to. Not where it start from:

```
$('section.active').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}).removeClass('active').next().show('slide', {direction: 'right'}).addClass('active');
```

So, how do I fix that?

Comment: You can do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24043188/1771795

Comment: One question, is it possible to make them slide at the same time? Right now the next slide is starting after the first finished.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamkarthik08/bthg9aus/) which I made for you. Hope it will give you an clear idea to achieve your solution.

```
<button type="button" class="slide-left">Slide Left</button>
<button type="button" class="slide-right">Slide Right</button>
<hr>
<div class="box">
    <div>Section 1</div>

</div>
<div>
     <div>Section 2</div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    var boxWidth = $(".box").width();
    $(".slide-left").click(function(){
        $(".box").animate({
            width: 0
        });
    });
    $(".slide-right").click(function(){
        $(".box").animate({
            width: boxWidth
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Omar's reference link I made this, working solution:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "[data-role='page']", function()
{

    $(this).find('section').not(":eq(0)").addClass("ui-screen-hidden");
    $(this).find("section:eq(0)").addClass("active");

    $(".ui-content").on("swipeleft swiperight", function (e)
    {

        var swipe = e.type,
            nextStep = $(this).find("section.active").next("section"),
            prevStep = $(this).find("section.active").prev("section");

        switch (true)
        {
            case (swipe == "swipeleft" && nextStep.length > 0):
                $(this).find("section.active")
                    .toggleClass("slide out");
                break;
            case (swipe == "swiperight" && prevStep.length > 0):
                $(this).find("section.active")
                    .toggleClass("slide out reverse");
                break;
        }
    });

}).on("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", "section", function (e)
{
    var elm = $(e.target);

    switch (true)
    {
        case (elm.hasClass("out") && !elm.hasClass("reverse")):
            $(elm).toggleClass("slide out ui-screen-hidden active");
            $(elm).next("section").toggleClass("slide in active ui-screen-hidden");
            break;
        case (elm.hasClass("out") && elm.hasClass("reverse")):
            $(elm).toggleClass("slide out ui-screen-hidden reverse active");
            $(elm).prev("section").toggleClass("slide in active reverse ui-screen-hidden");
            break;
        case (elm.hasClass("in") && !elm.hasClass("reverse")):
            elm.toggleClass("slide in");
            break;
        case (elm.hasClass("in") && elm.hasClass("reverse")):
            elm.toggleClass("slide in reverse");
            break;
    }
});
```